# pass parameters from HOC functional component to component doesn't work

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have HOC component and when I set a breakpoint I get the data properly, but when I'm passing the parameters to the component I don't get the props right

```
    const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(GET_STUDENTS);

    return (
        <Component studentsLoading={loading} error={error} students={data && data.students} {...props} />
    );
};
```

and the passed in component looks like that

```
const StudentList = ({error, studentsLoading, students}) => { }

export default withStudent(StudentList);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you said you are not getting props right, you are most likely overwriting HOC props with `...props` thus move it up and see if that works.

```
    <Component {...props} studentsLoading={loading} error={error} students={data && data.students}  />
               ^^^^^^^^^^
```